Middleware cannot be used with "output: export"
My files are as follows. I have been trying for several days with more than a thousand combinations but I always get the same result.

Middleware.js:

import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const protectedRoutes = ["/profile", "/assets", "/profile/[id]", "/"];
export const authRoutes = ["/admin/login"];
export const publicRoutes = [];

export function middleware(request) {

console.log(request.nextUrl.pathname);

if (protectedRoutes.includes(request.nextUrl.pathname)) {
console.log("test11");
return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/not-auth", request.url));
}

}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/assets/:path*", "/admin/:path*"],
};

The Directory Structure:
- src
   - app
      - lib.js
      - middleware.js


next.config.mjs:

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: false,
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  },
output: "export",
};

export default nextConfig;


Error: ⨯ Middleware cannot be used with "output: export". See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export
[x] Compiled /favicon.ico in 2.5s (611 modules)
GET /favicon.ico 200 in 1833ms
[] Middleware cannot be used with "output: export". See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export

I tried to remove the output: "export" parameter in the next.config.mjs file, but I can't get the project to build without it.

I can see that your middleware file isn't in the root of your project according to the directory structure you provided. Keep it at the level of src not app and try running the project again. Let me know if it still stays the same.

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports#unsupported-features specifically indicates that this is not supported.

I get the same error when I keep it in the src directory.

If this is not supported, what do I use?
